# Django redirect after save form in context_processor

Tags: django

I will if form saved, redirect my users. But it does'nt worked.

Error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

context_processor

```
from .models import StaticPages
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
def main(request):
    pages = StaticPages.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...
        contactform = ContactForm(request.POST)  # A form bound to the POST data
        if contactform.is_valid():  # All validation rules pass
            contactform.save()
            return redirect(reverse('index'))

    else:
        contactform = ContactForm()  # An unbound form
    context ={
        'pages':pages,
        'contactform':contactform

    }
    return(context)
```

my main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
...
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my core.urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import MainDashBoard

urlpatterns = [
    path('', MainDashBoard, name='index'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from service.models import Service
from product.models import Product
def MainDashBoard(request):
    service = Service.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context ={
        'service':service,
        'products':products
    }
    return render(request, "MainDashBoard.html", context=context)
```

Comment: Can you show your MainDashBoard? Does it have @login_required decorator?

Comment: No not used  @login_required. Because it's a public page.

I updated this quest for My MainDashBoard.

Comment: I can't find where the main()'s return **(context)** is used. I think the problem was raised while converting a tuple(main()'s return) to a dict.

Comment: Show the stack trace.